# How to translate super complicated compound English words/phrases into Spanish?

Tags: traducción

For example, some made up phrases are:

- The aircraft-carrier-oriented virtual-reality machine was turned off.
- The interesting old aircraft-carrier-oriented virtual-reality-videogame gear was literally completely gone.

These two sentences have a lot of "nesting" of structure. Take the last sentence and we'll break it down.

```
[
  interesting
  old
  [
    [
      [air-craft]
      [carry-er]
    ]
    [orient-ed]
  ] 
  [
    virtual
    reality
    [video-game]
    gear
  ]
]
```

And

```
[
  [literal-ly]
  [complete-ly]
]
```

The term "aircraft carrier" is two nouns, but "aircraft" is two nouns as well, so its nesting depth is 2. But it itself is part of an adjective phrase "aircraft-carrier-oriented", which is part of the phrase "interesting old aircraft-carrier-oriented virtual-reality-videogame gear". So there's like 3 or 4 levels of nesting there! And then `literal-ly` has nesting, as well as `complete-ly`, since they are "literal + [like (roughly)]" and "complete + [like (roughly)]", which is itself a nested phrase, etc.

How does Spanish translate such a sentence? I could imagine it being something like (obviously, picking the appropriate Spanish terms):

```
orientation of [de] carrier of [de] craft of [de] air that is [que] interesting and [y] old, ...?
```

But then I get lost. So wondering how you would translate such a complicated nested statement as that.

Comment: How about giving us a real phrase and not this: How can a virtual reality machine be oriented as an aircraft carrier?

Comment: What are those things in those grey boxes?? Very confusing. You have to work backwards: La maquina de realidad virtual orientada hacia un portaviones. The aircraft-carrier-oriented virtual-reality machine

Comment: @Lambie come on. If you try, it's directly interpreted that the grey boxes are the group of words displayed in a syntax that is describing the nested structure of what the OP is trying to translate. *How can a VR machine be oriented..." as just as it sounds. What's the problem with it? Also "very confusing" is not really helping and sounds, with respect, overstated.

Comment: @Lambie I really do not want you to get offended by my commentary *but* I also think this kind of responses is not encouraging anyone else to solve problems in a "socially oriented way" when getting lost. OP is providing both an example and a question, expliciting that can't do better, feeling "lost" or "complicated". `.SE`, as far as I know, is a place to find and provide answers to our questions, as a group of human beings, in a welltreating or "bientraitance" environment, and also bringing new ones when it's appropiate.

Comment: *Aircraft carrier* is not hyphenated https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aircraft%20carrier *Aircraft carrier-oriented* is correct, IMHO.

Comment: I simply do not understand how an aircraft carrier can be oriented a virtual reality machine. We say in English: An **object-oriented language** [in programming], but not an "aircraft carrier-oriented virtual reality machine". Which is why I ask that you make your statements relevant. That's all. Also, those chunks of grey text do not all relate to the question. Also, carrier, not carryer, not a word. And finally, what do literally or completely have to do with the question??

Comment: **The interesting, old aircraft carrier-oriented virtual reality videogame gear** =NOW yes. But still the issue of oriented as used here is confusing.

Comment: And: **The aircraft carrier-oriented virtual-reality machine**. So, you should make those corrections to your question, at the very least.

Comment: @Lambie Ok. I do get the point and I must agree with you. This question can (and should) be improved :-)

Comment: Clap, clap, clap. THANKS. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer*: this is only a try being a spanish (Chile) talker since (a bit after) I was born. Nobody specificly teached me english and I've never been or lived in an english-speaking country. I use the language to read scientific information. Also: I will write my answer `using all the grey boxes I wish`. I hope you don't find it *very* confusing. If, please reply with a comment.

---

### Before reading

`orientation of [de] carrier of [de] craft of [de] air that is [que] interesting and [y] old, ...?`

My first feel is that you're getting overwhelmed by the idea of "nested structure" when this shouldn't be "super complicated", at a first glance.

If you keep reading you will see that my proposed solution is similtar (maybe literal) compared to the 2nd example you provide.

- If you don't like to sound "extended" with the aircraft-carrier-oriented virtual-reality machine, maybe providing the information all together is not the best strategy.
- Are you writing something? old *and* aircraft-carrier-oriented are  ideas you can describe before, and *interesting* is something that can be infered when someone reads it.
- If you think it's interesting then you can say it before or after. So we're speaking of a VR gear, to sound less super complicated in terms of compound phrases, both in english and spanish.

---

### A possible solution

Ok. so, I copy the concept first. Now my logic on this is to understand it first. I move to the deepest level to catch what I'm reading about, and then I'm sort of "going up". Finally, I join every part.

```
[
  interesting
  old
  [
    [
      [air-craft]
      [carry-er]
    ]
    [orient-ed]
  ] 
  [
    virtual
    reality
    [video-game]
    gear
  ]
]
```

- It's a *gear*. What's a *gear* to me in spanish? It's equipment in this context, I guess. An accesory to be used to enhace the experience of the video-game. Then I'd say it depends (the translation) on the specific context. See [this](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oculus_Rift) "Oculus Rift" wikipedia page to ground what I'm saying.

```
Oculus Rift es un casco de realidad virtual que está siendo desarrollado por Oculus VR
```

- - so the type of the gear is often used to specify it directly. An example of some advertisement (sorry but first google results).

[image: Example]

- - it reads "visor", "gafas", "gafas y **equipos**". My most general candidate is equipment then.
- Moving on to "virtual reality gear", I then would say: "equipamiento de realidad virtual". As the "video-game" part is specifying the kind of software or hardware for the VR gear to be used, I would add "para video-juegos": you'd read "(el) equipamiento de realidad virtual para video-juegos".
- Next level is "air-craft carry-er - orient-ed". The "air-craft carry-er" is simplily a "portaaviones". *One* [meaning](https://dle.rae.es/portaaviones):

```
portaviones. 1. m. Buque de guerra dotado de las instalaciones necesarias para el transporte , despegue y aterrizaje de aparatos de aviación .
```

- - The literal translation would be "orientado a portaaviones", I tend to think.
- The next are just to adjectives of the object: "interesting and old", at the same level. "Viejo e interesante", at least for me. There are other words that maybe would fit better than "viejo". You know the context better than us.

---

### The answer

Now every bit can be joint, reading: "el (viejo e interesante) equipo (si es un *hardware* más complejo, o un equipamiento, si es un accesorio equipable, something you *wear*) de realidad virtual orientado a portaaviones". I write (viejo e interesante) because these are low level adjectives that are adding information that can be written inversely, I would think. You could say:

- El viejo e interesante equipo de realidad virtual orientado a portaaviones.
- El equipo de realidad virtual orientado a portaaviones viejo e interesante.

---

### Brief discussion and summary

First. I do not think that the question is confusing or misspelled or something else.

Moving to the solution, I prefer the first because it is not suggesting in any case that the carryers are old and interesting. So, if you stick with "El viejo e interesante equipo de realidad virtual orientado a portaaviones", readers thinking similar to me would interpret: this is a virtual reality gear oriented to the thing used to carry planes on, *and* the gear has the attribute of being both old and interesting".

- If you use the second alternative, maybe adding a coma would avoid misunderestandings.

If you would *not* want to say that, the solution would be other. My duty interpreting why this is old and interesting is out of the scope, e.g., I just imagined that we live in 2070 and there's a group of people being trained to move planes from a place to another, using an aircraft or another kind of motorized vehicle or whatever that is good to it, with a VR gear from 2021, that is old and interesting.

Good luck.

Best,

Comment: De acuerdo con visor o equipo y con 1)El viejo e interesante equipo de realidad virtual orientado a portaaviones(que ya estaba respondido por mí), pero me suena incorrecto "El equipo de realidad virtual orientado a portaaviones viejo e interesante." tanto por su ubicación como por la confusión que genera en la concordancia.. y donde ubicas y como pones o traduces "literally" y "completely". Gracias.

Comment: @cocteau siendo sincero creo no haber dado un ejemplo completo en respuesta al ejemplo provisto por la persona OP. Quizás es por eso que suena incorrecta la traducción de "literally" o "completely" ¿no? Quizás no comprendí bien. Me enfoqué simplemente en aclarar lo más nuclear de la pregunta: ordenar el asunto del *VR gear* desde mi experiencia hablando español y leyendo inglés. La segunda alternativa tampoco me convence, pero no me extrañaría que una persona hablante del español la utilizara. No suena completamente mal, y en la respuesta sugiero posibles sesgos desprendidos de su preferencia.

Comment: valoro tu análisis y tu extensa respuesta pero la opción 2) me suena foránea a cualquier tipo de español. Me refiero a que el OP por lo que entiendo quiere que literalmente y completely se inserten en su ejemplo(porque se incluyen en la frase original) => The interesting old aircraft-carrier-oriented virtual-reality-videogame gear was literally completely gone.

Answer (score 0):

- The /interesting/ /old/ &aircraft-carrier&(-oriented) >virtual-reality-videogame< gear was #literally# %completely% gone.
- The /interesting/ [y] /old/ gear [de] >videogame [de] reality virtual< (oriented [a]) &carrier aircraft& #literally# was gone %completely%
- El /interesante/ [y] /antiguo/ gear >[de] juegoS [de] realidad virtual< (orientado/enfocada [a]) &portaaviones& #literalmente# había desaparecido %[por] completo.%
- El /interesante/ [y] /antiguo/ gear >[de] realidad virtual< (orientado/enfocada [a]) &portaaviones& #literalmente# había desaparecido %[por] completo.%
- El /interesante/ [y] /antiguo/ gear >[de] realidad virtual< (orientado/enfocada [hacia]) LOS &portaaviones& #literalmente# había desaparecido %[por] completo.%
- El /interesante/ [y] /antiguo/ gear >[para] juegoS [de] realidad virtual< (orientado/enfocada [a]) &portaaviones& #literalmente# había desaparecido %[por] completo.%
- El /interesante/ [y] /antiguo/ gear >[diseñado para] juegoS [de] realidad virtual< (orientado/enfocada [a]) &portaaviones& #literalmente# había desaparecido %[por] completo.%
- El /interesante/ [y] /antiguo/ gear >[diseñado para] juegoS [de] realidad virtual< (que se enfoca [en]) (LOS) &portaaviones& #literalmente# había desaparecido %[por] completo.%

I'm not sure what you mean by gear. VR gear? Anyway, if it were plural, then I'd say "Los interesanteS y antiguoS...." AND (que se enfocaN [en])

Comment: I'm sorry but all the odd signs just make this really, really confusing.

Comment: @Lambie El interesante y antiguo gear diseñado para juegos de realidad virtual que se enfoca en portaaviones literalmente había desaparecido por completo, o bien, El interesante y antiguo gear de realidad virtual orientado/enfocado a portaaviones literalmente había desaparecido por completo.

Comment: @Lambie I also think it's a (little bit) odd way to cover all the possibilities to provide an answer.